# WinJS.Xhr change the user-agent

Tags: winjs, windows-phone-8.1

How can I change the user-agent of a xhr request ? 
It does not change when I set the header of the request :

```
 request = WinJS.xhr({
                url: url,
                data: params,
                type: "POST",
                headers : { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "User-Agent": "TEST" }
            });
```

The user agent is :
*User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 8.1; ARM; Trident/7.0; Touch; MSAppHost/2.0; rv:11.0; IEMobile/11.0; HTC; Windows Phone 8X by HTC) like Gecko*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [XMLHttpRequest specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader%28%29-method), which is used under the covers of WinJS.XHR, changes to the 'user-agent' header are terminated. I don't think there's a way around this. Maybe you can use a custom header?

> 5.Terminate these steps if header is a case-insensitive match for one of the following headers:
>
> - Accept-Charset
> - Accept-Encoding
> - Access-Control-Request-Headers
> - Access-Control-Request-Method
> - Connection Content-Length Cookie
> - Cookie2
> - Date
> - DNT
> - Expect
> - Host
> - Keep-Alive
> - Origin
> - Referer
> - TE
> - Trailer
> - Transfer-Encoding
> - Upgrade
> - **User-Agent**
> - Via

Answer (score 2):

Try using the Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient API instead, which allows much more flexibilit with things like setting headers. You can, for example, modify default headers with a user agent string, which is described in this topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn469430.aspx.

You can also use [HttpClient.sendRequestAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.httpclient.sendrequestasync.aspx) with a custom-built HttpRequestMessage object, in which you can set headers.

This API doesn't use XMLHttpRequest underneath like WinJS.xhr does, so you're not bound by that specification and can change the user agent string.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
window.navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', function () {
    return 'This is a newly mocked user Agent';
});
```